# python3 pandas move data into new columns if condition met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I have a dataframe:

```
names,individual
ABC LLC, business
John Smith, individual
```

How can I shift the names into a new column called 'businessname' if the 'individual' column='business'?

Desired output:

```
names,individual,businessname
null, business, ABC LLC
John Smith, individual, null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to move data into a column. One way particular to your problem is creating a column with selected data.

The following code creates a dataframe with your data

```
import pandas as pd

# Contruct dataframe
# names,individual
# ABC LLC, business
# John Smith, individual

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['names', 'individual'], data=[('ABC LLC', 'business'), ('John Smith', 'individual')])
```

create a mask to select only business

```
mask = df['individual'] == 'business'
```

add new column

```
df['business name'] = None
```

get the names from the business and set the business names

```
df.loc[mask, 'business name'] = df.loc[mask, 'names']
```

set the column rows of the column 'names' of the businesses to None

```
df.loc[mask, 'names'] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['businessman']=np.where(df['individual']=='business',df['names'],pd.NaN)
df['names']=np.where(df['individual']=='individual',df['names'],pd.NaN)
```

Comment: Hi, looks about right, you could try and explain what's is going on. Also have you heard about pandas.where?

Comment: np.where(condition, outcome if true, outcome if false) and no I haven't but that sounds like a neater approach.

Comment: Thank you @Vaishali2020!